# Make HTML file open in default browser instead of text editor in Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a script that generates some HTML pages, when this is done I open the index file of the generated pages. To do this I have this code:

```
if exist "generated_pages/index.html" start "" "generated_pages/index.html"
```

Right now the page opens in my default text editor for .html files, how can I make sure it opens in the user's default browser? I don't want to use commands for specific browsers as I don't know what the user's default browser will be.

Comment: I think it is opened in the default handler for .html files, which happens to be a text editor in your Windows account.

Comment: Change the default handler for `.html` extensions, or start the browser with the `.html` file as a parameter. If you're on Windows you could force IE to open it, but you should allow the file to be opened by the default handler, regardless.

Comment: The best way to display the page would be to use a small HTTP server -- [IIS Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264), for example, or [netcat or mongoose](https://serverfault.com/questions/255072/command-line-http-server-for-windows) if you prefer something install-less.  That would solve your file association conundrum, but it might also address other issues you haven't considered -- browser security preventing JavaScript from running within local files, for example.  You might also consider using `mshta.exe "generated_pages/index.html"` to view your html.

Comment: Use the `ASSOC /?` command to see how associations can be managed. You might also be interested in https://www.thewindowsclub.com/change-file-associations-windows

Comment: The thing is that this script is meant for other people on different computers, that's why I want the .html to open with the default browser and not a specific one like chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's no way to specify with the `start` command what type of program you wish to launch.  It will launch the default associated program based on the file's extension, and you're at the ill-fated mercy of the user's dubious choice of file association for .html files.  If you want to ensure your file gets opened only by a web browser and not by a text editor, then it'd be better to pass a URL into `start` than a filesystem location.  Using an http address as an argument to `start` should guarantee that the thing opening the location will be a web browser.

Serving your .html file over http can be done without relying on 3rd party binaries.  It's not prohibitively difficult to use .Net methods to create a rudimentary web server and serve the web page back over localhost.  That way you can `start "" "http://localhost:port/"` and you'll have a much better chance of avoiding opening the file in a text editor if your users have screwed up their file associations.

Save the following sorcery as a .bat script, tweak the html file name and location as needed, and give it a try.

```js
<# : httptest.bat -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689025/1683264
@echo off & setlocal

if exist test.html call :display test.html
goto :EOF

:display <htmlfile>
setlocal
set "infile=%~f1"
powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
endlocal & exit /b

: end Batch / begin PowerShell polyglot code #>
$tcpClient = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
while ($port = get-random -min 1024 -max 65535) {
    try {$tcpClient.Connect("localhost", $port)}
    catch {$tcpClient.Dispose(); break}
}
$endpoint = new-object Net.IPEndPoint([Net.IPAddress]::Any, $port)
$listener = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
$listener.start()
cmd /c start "" "http://localhost:$($port)/"
$client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
$stream = $client.GetStream()
if ($stream.CanRead) {
    [void]$stream.read((new-object byte[] 1024), 0, 1024);
}
if ($stream.CanWrite) {
    $content = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK`n`n$(gc $env:infile)"
    $out = [text.encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($content)
    $stream.write($out, 0, $out.length)
}
$stream.close()
$stream.dispose()
$listener.stop()
```

As a side benefit, serving your html over http can help you avoid tripping some browsers' security prohibiting JavaScript from executing from file:/// URLs.

---

If you want to include other referenced files, such as images, css files, sourced JavaScript files, etc, then that does get a little more tricky.  Here's a more thorough example that listens for an initial http request for up to 60 seconds, then continues serving relative-path sourced files as the browser requests them until no requests have been received for 5 seconds.  It should properly announce mime types of images and other sourced files.  If you need a longer timeout, change the `serve-content 5` line near the bottom.

```js
<# : httptest2.bat -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53689025/1683264
@echo off & setlocal

if exist "%~1" (call :display "%~1") else goto usage
goto :EOF

:usage
echo Usage: %~nx0 htmlfile
exit /b

:display <htmlfile>
setlocal
set "infile=%~f1"
powershell -noprofile "iex (${%~f0} | out-string)"
endlocal & exit /b

: end Batch / begin PowerShell polyglot code #>
Add-Type -as System.Web
$rootpath = (get-item $env:infile).DirectoryName
$filename = (get-item $env:infile).Name
$webname = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($filename)
$tcpClient = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpClient
while ($port = get-random -min 1024 -max 65535) {
    try {$tcpClient.Connect("localhost", $port)}
    catch {$tcpClient.Dispose(); break}
}
cmd /c start "" "http://localhost:$($port)/$webname"

function log($polarity, $txt) {
    $color = (("red","darkgray"),("green","white"))[$polarity]
    write-host -nonewline "[" -f $color[1]
    write-host -nonewline "*" -f $color[0]
    write-host "] $txt" -f $color[1]
}

function serve-content($seconds) {
    $timer = (get-date).AddSeconds($seconds)
    while (!$listener.Pending()) {
        start-sleep -milliseconds 10
        if ((get-date) -ge $timer) { return $false }
    }
    $client = $listener.AcceptTcpClient()
    $stream = $client.GetStream()
    if ($stream.CanRead) {
        $request = new-object byte[] 1024
        $size = $stream.read($request, 0, $request.length)
        $headers = [text.encoding]::UTF8.GetString($request, 0, $size)
        if ($stream.CanWrite) {
            $loc = $headers.split("`r?`n")[0] -replace "^\S+\s+|\s+HTTP/\d.+$"
            $loc = $loc -replace "^/", "$rootpath/" -replace "/", "\"
            $loc = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($loc)
            if ($loc) {
                if (!(test-path $loc -type leaf)) {
                    $loc = [Web.HttpUtility]::UrlDecode($loc)
                }
                if (test-path $loc -type leaf) {
                    $response = ,"HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
                    $mime = [Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping($loc)
                    $response += ,"Content-Type: $mime"
                    $response += ,"Content-Length: $((gi $loc).length)","",""
                    $out = [text.encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($response -join "`n"))
                    [byte[]]$body = gc $loc -enc byte
                    $out += $body
                    $stream.write($out, 0, $out.length)
                    log $true $loc
                }
                else {
                    $response = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found","",@"
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Error 404</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Not Found</h3>
        <p>The requested resource could not be located.</p>
    </body>
</html>
"@
                    $out = [text.encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(($response -join "`n"))
                    $stream.write($out, 0, $out.length)
                    log $false $loc
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $stream.close()
    $stream.dispose()
    $client.close()
    return $true
}

$endpoint = new-object Net.IPEndPoint([Net.IPAddress]::Any, $port)
$listener = new-object Net.Sockets.TcpListener $endpoint
$listener.start()

[void](serve-content 60)
while ((serve-content 5)) {}
$listener.stop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this works to other browsers, but for Chrome, this works just fine. You can open your `html` file with `chrome.exe` just like the following:

```bat
if exist "generated_pages/index.html" start "" "full\path\to\chrome.exe" file:///C:/example/generated_pages/index.html
```

Another way, would be to change the default handler for `html` files in your Windows Account. (`right-click to file` => `Open With...` => `select your browser` and `option "Open always html files..."`).

Comment: The thing is that this script is meant for other people on different computers, that's why I want the .html to open with the default browser and not a specific one like chrome.